# Naive bayes losses accuracy/precisionthe bigger the sample

Tags: feature-selection, naive-bayes, model-evaluation

I'm currently using a naive Bayes approach but I ran into a problem regarding the data sampling: the larger the dataset - the worse it starts to perform, even with a training. My features are for the most part all categorical.

What could explain this behaviour?

Comment: What is your data, it might have nothing to do with it being Bayesian.

Comment: Do you mean you are training on larger datasets and it's working worse, or testing? And how are you measuring _worse_?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if your precision decays with sample size, your model is the problem.